# R - count Shiny download button clicks

Tags: r, button, shiny

Is there a built in Shiny attribute that counts the number of times a downloadButton is clicked?  I'm not finding it in the function help or web searches.  If there's not a built in method how would I go about counting the clicks. Here's a working example:

```
data <- matrix(1:20, nrow=5)
ui <-  fluidPage(title = 'Count Button Clicks',
              fluidRow(style = "padding-bottom: 20px;",
                      column(width=6,
                             textOutput("actionclickCount"),
                             br(),
                             textOutput("downloadclickCount")
                             ),
                      column(width=6,
                             actionButton("actionBtn", "Action Button"),
                             br(),
                             downloadButton("dwnldBtn", "Download Button")
                             )
                      )
             )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$actionclickCount <- renderText({
      paste('Action Button Clicks =',input$actionBtn)
    })

    output$downloadclickCount <- renderText({
      paste('Download Button Clicks =','what variable goes here?')
    })

    output$dwnldBtn <- downloadHandler(
      filename = 'data.csv',
      content = function(file){
        write.csv(data, file)
      },
      contentType = 'csv'
    )
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no build-in method. But you could build it yourself.

You can do this by adding a click listener to the button with javascript:

```
  observe({
    if(is.null(input$rnd)){
      runjs("
            var click = 0;
            Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)
            var dwnldBtn = document.getElementById('dwnldBtn')
            dwnldBtn.onclick = function() {click += 1; Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)};
            ")      
    }
  })
```

The output from `Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)` will be accessible in Shiny via `input$rnd`.

Edit: For multiple buttons you can use:

```
  observe({
    for(btn1 in 1:2){
      if(is.null(input[[paste0("rnd", btn1)]])){
        runjs(
          paste0("
              var counter", btn1 ,"= 0;
              var dwnldBtn = document.getElementById('", paste0("dwnldBtn", btn1), "')
              dwnldBtn.onclick = function() {counter", btn1, " +=1; Shiny.onInputChange('", paste0("rnd", btn1), "', counter", btn1,")};
              ")
        )      
      }
    }
  })
```

For a working example see below:

```
   library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
data <- matrix(1:20, nrow=5)

ui <-  fluidPage(title = 'Count Button Clicks',
                 useShinyjs(),
                 fluidRow(style = "padding-bottom: 20px;",
                          column(width=6,
                                 textOutput("actionclickCount"),
                                 br(),
                                 textOutput("downloadclickCount")
                          ),
                          column(width=6,
                                 actionButton("actionBtn", "Action Button"),
                                 br(),
                                 downloadButton("dwnldBtn", "Download Button")
                          )
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$actionclickCount <- renderText({
    paste('Action Button Clicks =',input$actionBtn)
  })

  output$downloadclickCount <- renderText({
    paste('Download Button Clicks =', input$rnd)
  })

  output$dwnldBtn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'data.csv',
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(data, file)
    },
    contentType = 'csv'
  )

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$rnd)){
      runjs("
            var click = 0;
            Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)
            var dwnldBtn = document.getElementById('dwnldBtn')
            dwnldBtn.onclick = function() {click += 1; Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)};
            ")      
    }
    })

  }

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, which answered my question.  In application I actually have several download buttons.  I tried adding another downloadButton to your code and a count is added for both downloadButtons when either is clicked.  Is there a way to isolate the count for multiple download buttons?

Comment: I assume you gave them both the same id? For me naming the second one `downloadButton("dwnldBtn2", "Download Button")` works: The second button doesnt increase the counter then.

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to count the clicks for each downloadButton separably. I named the second one as you did: `downloadButton("dwnldBtn2", "Download Button")`.  I also added `dwnldClick2 = 0` to the global reactiveValues.  Under runjs I added  `var dwnldBtn2 = ...` and `dwnldBtn2.onclick = ...`.  Under the else I added `isolate(global$dwnldClick2 <- global$dwnldClick2 + 1)`.

Comment: I was using action buttons which worked perfectly on my local machine, but after uploading the app to the Shiny server I came into all kind of hang-ups.  I finally figured out I need the download handler and had to sort through more troubleshooting.  Only downside to this method is that I will loose my descriptive button IDs and have to use a common name + numeric sequence as an ID. But it works great and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It wouldn't let me before but you got it.

Comment: Use reactive functions! More idiomatic, no need to muck with JavaScript. https://gist.github.com/aagarw30/69feeeb7e813788a753b71ef8c0877eb