# Display "downloading" message in shiny-app when processing markdown file

Tags: shiny, markdown, knitr, download

I'm currently working on an application in Shiny (RStudio).
At the end of my application, I allow the user to download a markdown file with the most important results of the application (using downloadButton). 
However, the process of this file tends to take some time, so I was wondering whether there exists some code that allows me to inform the user that the markdown file is being knitted/downloaded.

On StackOverflow, I already found (and implemented on another position in my ui-file), the following code which displays a 'Loading...' message when Shiny is running a function (with many thanks to [user1603038](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325521/r-shiny-display-loading-message-while-function-is-running)):

```
conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                 tags$div(h3("Loading..."),
                          tags$p("This can take a few minutes."),
                          id="loadmessage"))
```

I thought that adapting the id-name would suffice for the code to work, but it doesn't. Did I do anything wrong? Am I not allowed to use this chunk of code multiple times?
I suspect that the knitting process does not concern Shiny itself. So, does there exists a similar class in html to indicate that the application is knitting a markdown file (e.g., hasClass('knitr-busy'), which unfortunately does not work)?

Alternatively, is there a way to inform the user that the downloadButton has been pressed and that RStudio is currently knitting the file (which value I -miraculously- should be able to reset after the markdown file has been generated)? I know that the actionButton in Shiny registers the amount of clicks on the button, but I'm not sure whether the downloadButton can provide a similar value...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe using `busyIndicator` from `shinysky` package?

Comment: Thank you for responding, but shinysky uses this "$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')" condition as well, so my question remains the same...

Comment: Will have to look into this deeper then. It's weird because I've used busy indicator  more than once in my app.

Comment: I found an answer to my question at the following page:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43663722/7084325 I agree with [SBista](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5894457/sbista) that multiple busy indicators are possible. Yet, I believe that the knitr-process does not involve shiny itself. As a result, I did not end up with any "loading..." comment.
Consequently, I looked for the alternative approach in which I used the amount of clicks on the downloadButton as an indicator to display a comment about the file being knitted. Thanks to [BigDataScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3502164/bigdatas