# R Shiny: remove newly created tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shiny app in which I want the user to be able to add and remove tabs. I know how to add tabs if the user clicks on a tab specifically made for that (thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503472/r-shiny-name-tabpanel-with-the-number-of-clicks)) but I can't figure out how to remove the lastly created tab.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",
                 title = "foo",
                 id = "tabs",
                 tabPanel(title = "Name 1",
                          fluidRow()),
                 tabPanel(title = "More",
                          icon = icon("plus"),
                          fluidRow()),
                 tabPanel(title = "Less",
                          icon = icon("minus"),
                          fluidRow())
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  count <- reactiveVal(1)

  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    if (input$tabs == "More"){
      count(count()+1)
      id = paste0("Name ", count())
      insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = id,
                         fluidRow(column(
                           width = 12))
                ), target = "More", position = "before",
                select = TRUE)}
    if (input$tabs == "Less"){
      count(count()+1)
      id = paste0("Name ", count())
      removeTab(inputId = "tabs",
                target = id
                )}
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here, you can see that clicking on the tab `More` adds a tab named `Name i` with `i` the number of clicks made on the tab `More`. However, clicking on the tab `Less` does nothing.

What I would like is the following:

- if the user clicks at least once on `More`, then clicking on `Less` removes the last created tab (therefore placed before `More`)
- if the user does not click on `More` then clicking on `Less` does nothing
- imagine that I click twice on `More` then there will be two additional tabs named `Name 2` and `Name 3`. Clicking on `Less` will remove `Name 3` but if I click again on `More`, the additional tab will be again called `Name 3` (therefore clicking on `Less` should not prevent the re-use of the name of the tab removed).

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this with adding selectors and having a button remove then reuse the selector indices. To do this using reactive values that count each time the individual button is pressed or logging when an interaction is done.

Give the below code a try:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",
                 title = "foo",
                 id = "tabs",
                 tabPanel(title = "Name 1",
                          fluidRow()),
                 tabPanel(title = "More",
                          icon = icon("plus"),
                          fluidRow()),
                 tabPanel(title = "Less",
                          icon = icon("minus"),
                          fluidRow())
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  count <- reactiveValues(value = 1)

  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    if (input$tabs == "More"){
      count$value <- count$value + 1
      id = paste0("Name ", count$value)
      insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = id,
                         fluidRow(column(
                           width = 12))
                ), target = "More", position = "before",
                select = TRUE)}
    if (input$tabs == "Less"){
      print(count$value)
      id = paste0("Name ", count$value)
      removeTab(inputId = "tabs",
                target = id
      )

      count$value <- count$value -1
      }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: that's perfect but there is one flaw (due to something I didn't mention in my problem so that's my fault): when I click on ```Less``` twice, it will only remove the lastly created tab but the second click will be useless. I would like that clicking twice on ```Less``` removes the two lastly created tabs, do you know how to fix it? Thanks anyway for your solution