# Access dataframes created through modules with their names and store them in a list

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an app with modules, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939628/replicating-identical-tabs-and-layouts-over-and-over). Basically, it is an app in which it is possible to create identical tabs with different input names, just by clicking on a tab called `More`.

Now, I would like to give the user the possibility to merge some (or all) of the tables created. To do so, there is a (permanent) tab called `Merge` in which there is a `checkBoxInput`. When no tab is created, this `checkBoxInput` is empty (since there are no tab and hence no table to select). When one tab and therefore one table are created, I would like the `checkBoxInput` to be updated to display a box and the name corresponding to this table. For example, if I create 3 tabs, then there should be 3 boxes in the `checkBoxInput`.

My idea so far was to store the tables created in a list and to update `checkBoxInput` with the content of this list each time a tab and a table are created. However, I don't know how to obtain the name of the tables created in a module. Since the tables are named with `x` in the module `moduleTable`, I thought I could just use `x` but it gives me the following error:

> Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: object 'x' not found

Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

addTab <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("select"),
                "Choose", 
                choices = colnames(mtcars)),
    tableOutput(ns("table"))
  )
}

moduleTable <- function(input, output, session){
  x <- reactive(select(mtcars, input$select))
  output$table <- renderTable({
    x()
  })
}


ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",
                 title = "foo",
                 id = "tabs",
                 tabPanel(title = "Merge",
                          fluidRow(
                            checkboxGroupInput("to_merge",
                                               label = "Tables to merge",
                                               choices = NULL)
                          )),
                 tabPanel(title = "More",
                          icon = icon("plus"),
                          fluidRow()
                          )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveValues(val=0)

  dfs <- list()

  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    if (input$tabs == "More"){
      count$val <- count$val+1
      name <- paste0("Name ", count$val)
      insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = name,
                         addTab(paste0("select", count$val))
                ), 
                target = "More", 
                position = "before",
                select = TRUE)

      callModule(moduleTable, paste0("select", count$val))

      dfs[[count$val]] <- paste0("mtcars$select", count$val)
      # UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW AND COMMENT THE LINE ABOVE TO SEE THE PROBLEM
      # tables[[count$val]] <- x

      names(dfs[count$val]) <- paste0("df", count$val)

      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session,
                               inputId = "to_merge",
                               choices = names(dfs))
    }
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I obtain the names of the dataframes created and store them in a reactive list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following code to return the reactive expression and join the table.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

addTab <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("select"),
                "Choose", 
                choices = colnames(mtcars[, -1])),
    tableOutput(ns("table"))
  )
}

moduleTable <- function(input, output, session){
  x <- reactive(select(mtcars, c(mpg, input$select)))
  output$table <- renderTable({
    x()
  })
  return(x)
}


ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",
                 title = "foo",
                 id = "tabs",
                 tabPanel(title = "Merge",
                          fluidRow(
                            checkboxGroupInput("to_merge",
                                               label = "Tables to merge",
                                               choices = NULL),
                            tableOutput("table")
                          )),
                 tabPanel(title = "More",
                          icon = icon("plus"),
                          fluidRow()
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveValues(val=0)
  tables <- reactiveValues()

  dfs <- list()

  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    if (input$tabs == "More"){
      count$val <- count$val+1
      name <- paste0("Name ", count$val)
      insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = name,
                         addTab(paste0("select", count$val))
                ), 
                target = "More", 
                position = "before",
                select = TRUE)

      x <- callModule(moduleTable, paste0("select", count$val))
      tables[[name]] <- x
    }
  })

  observe({
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session,
                             inputId = "to_merge",
                             choices = names(tables),
                             selected = input$to_merge)
  })

  observe({
    req(input$to_merge)
    output$table <- renderTable({
      if(!is.null(input$to_merge)) {
        tabs <- map(input$to_merge, ~{tables[[.x]]()})
        reduce(tabs, full_join)
      }
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (getting a bit closer but not there yet):

I know that modules can return data (as `reactiveValues`). So my challenge now is to return the data in your `x()`. With some random non-reactive values, it works in the sense that I can collect (append) the output of a module call in a variable and then show these values as a string for example. Here is where I am:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

addTab <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        selectInput(ns("select"),
                    "Choose", 
                    choices = colnames(mtcars)),
        tableOutput(ns("table"))
    )
}

moduleTable <- function(input, output, session){
    x <- reactive(select(mtcars, input$select))
    output$table <- renderTable({
        x()
    })

    table_list <- reactiveValues()

    table_list$test <- sample(letters, 1)
    table_list$first_value <- x()[1,1]

    return(table_list)
}

ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",
                 title = "foo",
                 id = "tabs",
                 tabPanel(title = "Merge",
                    fluidRow(
                            checkboxGroupInput("to_merge",
                                               label = "Tables to merge",
                                               choices = NULL),
                            textOutput("string"),
                            textOutput("first_value")
                        )),
                    tabPanel(title = "More",
                             icon = icon("plus"),
                             fluidRow()
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    vals <- reactiveValues(val = 0, name = "", string_output = NULL, first_value = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$tabs, {
        if (input$tabs == "More"){
            vals$val <- vals$val+1
            name <- paste0("Name ", vals$val)
            insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                                tabPanel(title = name,
                                         addTab(paste0("select", vals$val))
                                ), 
                                target = "More", 
                                position = "before",
                                select = TRUE)

            m_output <- callModule(moduleTable, paste0("select", vals$val))

            vals$string_output <- c(vals$string_output, m_output$test)
            vals$first_value <- c(vals$first_value, m_output$first_value)

            vals$name[vals$val] <- paste0("mtcars$select", vals$val, "_", m_output$test)

            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session,
                                     inputId = "to_merge",
                                     choices = vals$name)

            output$string <- renderText({
                req(input$tabs)
                paste(vals$string_output, collapse = ", ")  
            })

            output$first_value <- renderText({
                req(input$tabs)
                paste(vals$first_value, collapse = ", ")        # This doesn't work as expected 
            })

            }
    })  
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How about this?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

addTab <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        selectInput(ns("select"),
                                "Choose", 
                                choices = colnames(mtcars)),
        tableOutput(ns("table"))
    )
}

moduleTable <- function(input, output, session){
    x <- reactive(select(mtcars, input$select))
    output$table <- renderTable({
        x()
    })
}

ui <- navbarPage(position = "static-top",
                                 title = "foo",
                                 id = "tabs",
                                 tabPanel(title = "Merge",
                                                 fluidRow(
                                                    checkboxGroupInput("to_merge",
                                                                                         label = "Tables to merge",
                                                                                         choices = NULL)
                                                 )),
                                 tabPanel(title = "More",
                                                 icon = icon("plus"),
                                                 fluidRow()
                                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    vals <- reactiveValues(val=0, name = "")
    dfs <- list()

    observeEvent(input$tabs, {
        if (input$tabs == "More"){
            vals$val <- vals$val+1
            name <- paste0("Name ", vals$val)
            insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                                tabPanel(title = name,
                                                 addTab(paste0("select", vals$val))
                                ), 
                                target = "More", 
                                position = "before",
                                select = TRUE)

            callModule(moduleTable, paste0("select", vals$val))

            vals$name[vals$val] <- paste0("mtcars$select", vals$val)

            print(vals$name)
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session,
                                     inputId = "to_merge",
                                     choices = vals$name)
        }
    })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Not sure I quite understand and if that is what you are looking for, or would you like to have all your tables from the module in a list (so not just a naming problem?)

Comment: well I would like to merge the tables whose boxes were ticked so I'm not sure if this solution will allow to use the selected tables. The merged dataframe is supposed to appear in the ```Merge``` panel. I will try to achieve this with your answer and I'll mark your answer as a solution if I can do it. If you have an idea on how to do it, please add it to your post.