# How to use JS to count the number of clicks of a selectInput function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny-reactivity

In running the below code, each click of the `actionButton()` is correctly counted and output to the UI (using reactive value **y**). I'm trying to do the same with `selectInput()` (counting each time a selection is made)(using reactive value **x**), but it doesn't completely correctly count because when first invoking the App, selecting the default choice of "Cyl" is not included in the count (I'd like it to), and clicking the same choice more than once isn't included in the count (I'd like all clicks counted). One workaround is to include "multiple = TRUE" in the `selectInput()`, but I'd like to see if there's a JS solution instead so I don't have to change the UI the way including "multiple = TRUE" does.

As an aside, using "multiple = TRUE" also corrects the weird subtraction of 1 from (x) in `output$clickSelInput...`; hopefully a JS solution does the same.

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(hr(),
  selectInput("selInput",label=NULL,c("Cyl"="cyl","Trans"="am","Gears"="gear"),selected=NULL),
  actionButton("addBtn","Add"), hr(),
  textOutput("clickSelInput"),
  textOutput("clickAddBtn"),
  tableOutput("data")
)
  
server = function(input, output) {
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  y = reactiveVal(0)
    
  output$data <- renderTable({mtcars[1:10, c("mpg", input$selInput), drop = FALSE]})
    
  observeEvent(input$selInput,{x(x()+1)})
  observeEvent(input$addBtn,{y(y()+1)})
    
  output$clickSelInput <- renderText({paste('Select Input clicks =',x()-1)})
  output$clickAddBtn <- renderText({paste('Add Button clicks =',y())})
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - count Shiny download button clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663352/r-count-shiny-download-button-clicks)

Comment: Thank you SamR, that was helpful by analogy. I had to make more changes to make this work such as moving the `selectInput()` into the server section using `renderUI()`.

Comment: Great glad it was useful and thanks for posting the solution and highlighting the differences so others can benefit in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution, taking SamR's suggestion into account and using that example by analogy. I had to make other changes to make it work. I commented changes below from OP.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) # added

ui = fluidPage(hr(),
 useShinyjs(), # added, this line is easy to forget to add
 uiOutput("selInput"),  # added, pulls renderUI output from server into UI 
 actionButton("addBtn","Add"), hr(),
 textOutput("clickSelInput"),
 textOutput("clickAddBtn"),
 tableOutput("data")
)

server = function(input, output) {
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  y = reactiveVal(0)
  
  output$data <- renderTable({mtcars[1:10, c("mpg", input$selInput), drop = FALSE]})

  observeEvent(input$addBtn,{y(y()+1)})
  
  # moved select input into renderUI so it can interact with JS in the observe further down:
  output$selInput <- renderUI(
      selectInput("selInput",label=NULL,c("Cyl"="cyl","Trans"="am","Gears"="gear"),selected=NULL)
    )
  
  output$clickSelInput <- renderText({paste('Select Input clicks =',input$rnd)}) # changed
  output$clickAddBtn <- renderText({paste('Add Button clicks =',y())})
  
  # added js:
  observe({
    if(is.null(input$rnd)){
      runjs("
            var click = 0;
            Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)
            var selInput = document.getElementById('selInput')
            selInput.onclick = function() {click += 1; Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)};
            ")      
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```